# How to change file permission when copying by add_custom_command in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I am able to copy files by cmake using something like

```
file(GLOB IMAGES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Image/*)
file(COPY ${IMAGES} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Image
     FILE_PERMISSIONS OWNER_READ OWNER_WRITE GROUP_WRITE GROUP_READ WORLD_READ)
```

but the downside is this command will only be invoked when cmake is reconfigured. I figured out a way to copy them whenever a build is triggered like below

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
                  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Image"
                  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Image")
```

this suits my needs by I am not able to figure out a way to alter the file permission like the first method. I need to alternate the file permission to make sure it is right otherwise some images might be wrongly classified as executable when running the below command

```
find . -executable -type f
```

Is it possible to alter the file permission when copying from add_custom_command?

Comment: The `copy`, `copy_directory` and `copy_if_different` commands should not alter the file permissions. If they do, you should file it as a bug to CMake. I don't see a CMake-only way to alter the file permissions with the `cmake` command line. Seems the images are marked as executable already in the source directory.

Comment: @Torbjörn That's unfortunate. In my experience the file permissions gets alternated unexpectedly when pushed and pulled across different OS. I will file a feature request to CMake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMake developers actually responds back with an answer that works. The key is creating a temporary cmake script with file(COPY) in it and invoke it.

```
    file(GLOB IMAGES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Image/*")

    file(WRITE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foo.cmake" "file(COPY ${IMAGES} 
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Image 
    FILE_PERMISSIONS OWNER_READ OWNER_WRITE GROUP_WRITE GROUP_READ WORLD_READ)")

    add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD COMMAND 
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foo.cmake)
```