# How to get current configuration (Release/Debug) in CMake for Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, cmake

I am on Visual Studio 2013, CMake 3.5.1, Windows 10. I am trying to copy some files via CMake like below:

```
file(COPY ${IMAGES} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Release)
```

Is it possible to replace "Release" with a variable that represents the configuration like:

```
file(COPY ${IMAGES} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/${Variable})
```

I attempted

```
file(COPY ${IMAGES} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})
```

but CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is an empty string when I use message to print it out, I also attempted

```
file(COPY ${IMAGES} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/$<CONFIGURATION>)
```

but for some reason file command cannot decipher `$<CONFIGURATION>` whereas command like

```
add_custom_target(run COMMAND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/$<CONFIGURATION>/Test.exe)
```

can. What is the right way to extract whether visual studio is currently built in Release or Debug in CMake?

Comment: I still can not understand: I made a VS solution by calling `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" ..` and now I have an *.sln project with `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES=Debug;Release;MinSizeRel;RelWithDebInfo` (it's pretty standard, I guess). I am able to change the configuration using the configuration manager (or dropdown). How can I retrieve currently selected Configuration in `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: @Netherwire You don't know what is selected during CMake config time, meaning prior to the generation of the sln file. `add_custom_target` works because the custom target is invoked after the sln file is generated manually or programmatically.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `file` command is executed during CMake runtime, not during build time (i.e. VS runtime).

This also means, that the generator expressions (e.g. `$<CONFIG>`) can not be used, as these are evaluated during build time.
(*Hint: As long as there is no explicit reference to the use of generator expressions for a particular command in the CMake docu, they are not supported by that command*).

The reason, why `${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}` is empty, is due to the reason that you probably haven't specified it on the invocation of CMake:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
```

However, using that, would mean that the build files are only generated for the *Debug* configuration. That's obviously not what you want.

To solve your problem: Using generator expressions is the right way, as you've already figured out with the use of `add_custom_target` (or `add_custom_command`).

You can use custom commands as dependencies for other "*real*" targets and you can specify post-/pre-build and pre-link commands for a specific target via [`add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events).

As the docu states for the `COMMAND` argument of `add_custom_command`:

> Arguments to `COMMAND` may use generator expressions. References to target names in generator expressions imply target-level dependencies, but NOT file-level dependencies. List target names with the `DEPENDS` option to add file-level dependencies.

To copy a file after a successful build of a target:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET myTarget POST_BUILD
                   COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E copy_if_different "${IMAGE1}" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/$<CONFIG>/"
                   COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E copy_if_different "${IMAGE2}" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/$<CONFIG>/"
)
```

Comment: If add_custom_command is the way to go for build time, could you also please answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/39282243/3667089

Comment: Seems like great advice, just _cannot_ get it to work. #$%